# How to setup a CoreML model?

Tags: ios, swift, model, coreml

I'm having some problems setting up a Core ML model...

Xcode tells me : "init() is deprecated: Use init(configuration:) instead and handle errors appropriately."

Here is my code:

```
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: MobileNetV2().model) else {
        fatalError("Unable to load the model")
    }
    
    let classificationRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: classificationCompleteHandler)
    classificationRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOption.centerCrop
    visionRequests = [classificationRequest]
    
    loopCoreMLUpdate()
}
```

How can I solve that?

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Loïc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is literally in the error message: don't use the init without arguments, use `init(configuration:)` to instantiate the model.

```
let config = MLModelConfiguration()
guard let coreMLModel = try? MobileNetV2(configuration: config),
      let visionModel = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: coreMLModel.model) else {
```

The reason for this change is that the deprecated `init()` does not have a way to tell you that loading the model may have failed.